# Zero downtime restart of unicorn/ rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

In our deploy scripts we use the following snippet to restart unicorn:

```
desc "Zero downtime restart of Unicorn"
task :restart do
  run "kill -s USR2 unicorn_pid"
end
```

The master process forks, starts the new workers and then kills the old one. But now it seems the new master kills the old master and takes over any new connections *before* the new children are fully up. As we disabled preloading of the app using `preload_app false` the new workers take around 30 - 60 seconds to start. During this time the new connections/ the website hangs. How to avoid this, so making the new master only take over once the new children are fully up and ready to server requests? :)

Update:

My unicorn.rb looks like this:

```
# name of application
application = "myapp"

# environment specific stuff
case ENV["RAILS_ENV"]
when "integration", "staging"
  worker_processes 1
when "production"
  worker_processes 4
else
  raise "Invalid runtime environment '#{ENV["RAILS_ENV"]}'"
end

# set directories
base_dir = "/srv/#{application}/current"
shared_path = "/srv/#{application}/shared"
working_directory base_dir

# maximum runtime of requests
timeout 300

# multiple listen directives are allowed
listen "#{shared_path}/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

# location of pid file
pid "#{shared_path}/pids/unicorn.pid"

# location of log files
stdout_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.log"
stderr_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.err"

# combine REE with "preload_app true" for memory savings
# http://rubyenterpriseedition.com/faq.html#adapt_apps_for_cow
preload_app false
if GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=)
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true
end

before_exec do |server|
  # see http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Sandbox.html
  ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = "#{base_dir}/Gemfile"
end

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # the following is highly recomended for "preload_app true"
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end
  if defined?(Sequel::Model)
    Sequel::DATABASES.each{ |db| db.disconnect }
  end

  # This allows a new master process to incrementally
  # phase out the old master process with SIGTTOU to avoid a
  # thundering herd (especially in the "preload_app false" case)
  # when doing a transparent upgrade. The last worker spawned
  # will then kill off the old master process with a SIGQUIT.
  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if old_pid != server.pid
    begin
      sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU
      Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```

I think the main problem is that there's no `child_ready` hook. The `before_fork` and `after_hook` are called "too early". I think I could add some logic in the `after_fork` hook to somehow detect when a child is ready...but I hope there's an easier solution? :)

Comment: Could you also show your unicorn config file?

Comment: From my experience I old master is never killed without manual intervention. Give `HUP` a try in favor of `USR2`, also have a look at the signals docs for Unicorn http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html